# how to optimize QPainter performance

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to make an application to simulate LED screen, which can display some text and scroll. So I came up with the idea of using `QGraphView`. I can draw a Ellipse to represent an LED lamp bead. I make the `Grid` class, which is used to layout these Ellipses. First, I will call the `generate_grid` method to generate each Ellipse. Then, call the `update_pixel` method to display the text. It can work perfectly. But when i want to scroll the text, the CPU usage will be high, and the graphics will not be smooth. My Cpu is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz   2.30 GHz`.
[image]

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QTimer;
class QGraphicsScene;
class QGraphicsView;
class QGraphicsEllipseItem;

class Grid final : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Grid(QGraphicsScene * scene, QObject * parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QObject(parent), m_scene(scene) {}
    virtual ~Grid() {}

    inline uint get_gap() const { return this->m_gap; }
    inline uint get_pixel_width() const { return m_grid_size.width(); }
    inline uint get_pixel_height() const { return m_grid_size.height(); }

    void generate_grid(const QColor & color);
    void update_pixel(uint x, uint y, const QColor & color);

private:
    static constexpr uint default_size = 10;
    static constexpr uint default_gap = default_size + 2;
    static constexpr uint default_start_x = 10;
    static constexpr uint default_start_y = 10;

    uint m_size = default_size;
    uint m_gap = default_gap;
    uint m_startX = default_start_x;
    uint m_startY = default_start_y;
    QSize m_grid_size = {32, 150};
    QGraphicsScene * m_scene;
    QVector<QGraphicsEllipseItem *> m_items;
};

/***********************************************************/
struct varSection final
{
    uint offset = 0;
    uint width = 0;
    uint height = 0;
    uint real_width = 0;
    QString str_point;

    uint get_max_width() const { return std::max(this->real_width, this->width); }
};

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

     virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;

private slots:
    void handle_section_move();
private:
    void init_widget();

private:
    Grid * m_grid = Q_NULLPTR;
    QTimer * m_timer = Q_NULLPTR;
    QGraphicsView * m_view = Q_NULLPTR;
    varSection m_section;

};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>


void Grid::generate_grid(const QColor & color)
{
    for (int cur = m_items.size(); cur <= m_grid_size.height() * m_grid_size.width(); ++cur)
    {
        QGraphicsEllipseItem * pItem = this->m_scene->addEllipse(QRect());
        m_items.push_back(pItem);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_grid_size.height(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_grid_size.width(); j++)
        {
            int idx = i * m_grid_size.width() + j;
            if (idx >= m_items.size()) continue;

            QGraphicsEllipseItem * pItem = m_items[i * m_grid_size.width() + j];
            if (pItem)
            {
                pItem->setRect(QRect(m_startX + m_gap * i, m_startY + m_gap * j, m_size, m_size));
                pItem->setPen(color);
                pItem->setBrush(color);
                pItem->show();
            }
        }
    }
}

void Grid::update_pixel(uint x, uint y, const QColor & color)
{
    int idx = x * m_grid_size.width() + y;
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= m_grid_size.height() * m_grid_size.width()) return;

    m_items[idx]->setPen(color);
    m_items[idx]->setBrush(color);
}

/******************************************************************************/
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->init_widget();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::init_widget()
{
    m_view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    m_view->setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
    m_view->setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView::DontSavePainterState, true);
    m_view->setOptimizationFlag(QGraphicsView::DontAdjustForAntialiasing, true);
//    m_view->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::NoViewportUpdate);
    m_view->resize(QSize(this->width(), this->height()));

    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
    scene->addEllipse(QRect(0, 0, 1, 1));

    m_view->setScene(scene);

    m_grid = new Grid(scene, this);
    m_grid->generate_grid(Qt::gray);

    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Widget::handle_section_move);
    m_timer->start(1000 / 30);

    m_section.str_point =
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011110001100001100011000000001100011000000000000011001100110000001111001100000000000"
            "00000000000000011000000000000110110000000000000000000000000000000011001100110001100001100000000110011000000000000001100110110000"
            "00110011011000000000000000000000000001100000000000011011000000000000000000000000000000001100000011000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000011001100000000011000001100000000000000000000000000110000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000000111000011110011110"
            "01100111100110110011011011000001100110111000001100000111110001111001101100011111011111000111100110110000111100000000000000000000"
            "00000111000011000000110110110011011011001101110110000110011001100000110000011001101100110111011011001101100110000011011011000110"
            "01100000000000000000000000001110001100000011011011100001101100110110011000011001100110000011000001100110110011011001101100110110"
            "01100000110110110001100110000000000000000000000000011100110001111101100111100110110011011001100001100110011000001100000110011011"
            "00110110011011001101100110011111011011000111111000000000000000000000000000110011001100110110000111011011001101100110000110011001"
            "10000011000001100110110011011001101100110110011011001101101100011000000000000000000000000000000011001100110011011000001101101100"
            "11011001100001100110011000001100000110011011001101100110110011011001101100110110110001100000000000000000000000000011001100110011"
            "00110110110011011011001101100110000110011001100000110011011001101100110110011011001101100110110011011011100110000000000000000000"
            "00000000011110000110011111011001111001100111110110011000001111001111000001111001100110011110011001100111110110011001111101100111"
            "00111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    m_section.width = 150;
    m_section.height = 32;
    m_section.real_width = 131;

    this->resize(1500, 500);
}

void Widget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    m_view->resize(QSize(this->width(), this->height()));
}

void Widget::handle_section_move()
{
    uint offset = m_section.offset % (m_section.real_width + m_section.width + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_section.str_point.size(); ++i)
    {
        uint posx = (i % m_section.get_max_width()) + m_section.width - offset;
        uint posy = (i / m_section.get_max_width());
        if (posx < 0 || posy < 0 || posx >= 150 || posy >= 32) continue;

        m_grid->update_pixel(posx, posy, m_section.str_point[i] == '1' ? Qt::blue : Qt::gray);
    }

    m_section.offset++;
}
```

Please ignore the source of `m_section`, which comes from another project of mine. The code here is only used to demonstrate this problem.

If I revise `update_pixel` method, as follow.

```
void Grid::update_pixel(uint x, uint y, const QColor & color)
{
    int idx = x * m_grid_size.width() + y;
    if (idx < 0 || idx >= m_grid_size.height() * m_grid_size.width()) return;

   //m_items[idx]->setPen(color);
   //m_items[idx]->setBrush(color);
}
```

the CPU usage will be lower. I know that `QPainter` will eventually be called here to render graphics. I need to scroll at 30 steps per second, or faster. How can I optimize this program or any other solution?

Comment: Do not use `QGraphicsView`, it is complicated overkill. Just render the text to `QImage` or `QPixmap` and then only scroll the image or pixmap. It will be much much faster.

Comment: Note that you could probably implement this quite easily with `OpenGL` ([`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qopenglwidget.html) etc.).  Just blend textures onto a quad.  The CPU usage should all but disappear.